# p5.js collision between array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections, detection, p5.js

I am learning p5.js and I have come upon a problem that I cannot yet solve.
So I'm making this little game in which you have to shoot the enemies and dodge their skills. This is how to looks:[image]

On the right side we have the player, in the middle the bullet ( that is handled with an array ) and on the left side the enemies ( an array ). Both enemies and the bullets have their own object.
This is the code to spawn the enemies and the bullets:

For bullets

```
function shoot() {
    x = p.x + 6.5;
    y = p.y + 12.5;
    bullets.push(new Bullet(x, y));
}
```

for enemies:

```
function spawnEnemies() {
    let x = 650;
    let y = 30;

    for (let i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
        enemies.push(new Enemy(x, y));
        y += 40
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do, is to detect the collision when the bullet reaches the targets. This is how I tried it:

```
// check hit
for (let i = 0; i < bullets.length; i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < enemies.length; j++){
        let d = dist(bullets[i].x, bullets[i].y, enemies[j].x, enemies[j].y)
        if (d < 1){
            console.log('hit');
        }
    }
}
```

The `check hit` code is inside of p5's `draw` function, therefore it is executed continuously. Can anyone help me out?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for collision inside `draw` loop. With circles is simple you can just check if distance is less then sum of two elements radiuses [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/99486xh1/5/)

```
dist < circleOne.radius + circleTwo.radius
```

But since you have squares then its little more difficult because `size != diagonal` so the code could look something like this. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/99486xh1/15/)

```
if (Math.abs(this.position.x - player.position.x) < this.size/2 + player.size/2 && Math.abs(this.position.y - player.position.y) < this.size/2 + player.size/2) collision = true;
```

Also here I used `p5.Vector` for position but you don't have to, just use `dist` instead of `p5.Vector.dist`

```js
const targets = [];
let player = null;
let canvas = null;

function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas(400, 400);
  player = new Player(0, 0, 30, 'green');

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const w = random(width);
    const h = random(height);
    const size = random(5, 40);
    targets.push(new Target(w, h, size, 'blue'));
  }

  canvas.mouseMoved(function() {
    player.position.x = mouseX;
    player.position.y = mouseY;
  })
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  player.show()
  targets.forEach(target => {
    target.show();
    target.hit(player)
  })
}

class Element {
  constructor(x, y, size, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
    this.color = color;
    this.position = new p5.Vector(this.x, this.y);
  }

  show() {
    fill(this.color);
    rectMode(CENTER)
    rect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.size, this.size)
  }
}

class Player extends Element {}
class Target extends Element {
  hit(player) {
    let collision = false;

    if (Math.abs(this.position.x - player.position.x) < this.size / 2 + player.size / 2 && Math.abs(this.position.y - player.position.y) < this.size / 2 + player.size / 2) collision = true;
    else collision = false;
    if (collision) this.color = 'red';
    else this.color = 'blue';
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

To detect collision between two arrays of elements you could use nested `for` loop because you need to check if any element from first array collide with any element from second array.

```js
const targets = [];
const bullets = [];
let canvas = null;

function setup() {
  canvas = createCanvas(400, 400);

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    const w = random(width);
    const h = random(height);
    const size = random(5, 50);
    targets.push(new Target(w, h, size, 'blue'));
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < 30; j++) {
    const w = random(width);
    const h = random(height);
    const size = random(5, 20);
    bullets.push(new Bullet(w, h, size, 'green'));
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  bullets.forEach(bullet => {
    bullet.show();
    bullet.move();
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < bullets.length; j++) {
      const hit = targets[i].hit(bullets[j]);
      if (hit) {
        targets[i].color = 'red';
        break;
      } else targets[i].color = 'blue'
    }
  }

  targets.forEach(target => target.show());
}

class Element {
  constructor(x, y, size, color) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
    this.color = color;
    this.position = new p5.Vector(this.x, this.y);
  }

  show() {
    const c = color(this.color);
    c.setAlpha(150);
    fill(c);
    rectMode(CENTER)
    rect(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.size, this.size)
  }
}

class Bullet extends Element {
  move() {
    this.position.add(p5.Vector.random2D())
  }
}
class Target extends Element {
  hit(player) {
    if (Math.abs(this.position.x - player.position.x) < this.size / 2 + player.size / 2 && Math.abs(this.position.y - player.position.y) < this.size / 2 + player.size / 2) return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: The check collision is already inside the draw loop.. My problem is that I have an `array` of bullets and an enemies. So I ahve to check for each of them. Becuse is player shoots more bullets than the array has more elements.